# for loop - checking if numbers in array move more up or down

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am using a for loop to check whether the array i enter in as a parameter has more ups or downs in terms of integers. I am not sure why but my compiler is throwing an index out of bounds exception. Would be nice if someone can just point it out.

```
public boolean moreUpsThanDowns(int[] a)
{
    int counterup = 0;
    int counterdown = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i <= a.length ; i++){
        if (a[(i+1)] - a[i] > 0 ){
            counterup++;
        } else if(a[(i+1)] - a[i] < 0 ){
            counterdown++;
        } else if(a[(i+1)] - a[i] == 0 ){
            counterup = counterup;
            counterdown = counterdown;
        }
    }

    if (counterup > counterdown){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's *waay* out of bounds. You're letting `i` run up to `a.length` although the last valid index is `a.length-1` and you're indexing with `a[i+1]` so you're off two at least.

Comment: Replace "int i=0 ; i <= a.length ; i++" with "int i=0 ; i < a.length ; i++". Also for the last element avoid doing i+1. There is no last after last.

Comment: You Should Change Your for loop with  for(int i=0 ; i < a.length-1 ; i++) just because when you try to use a[i+1] it should not go higher then a.length that is cause of your index out of bounds exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small semantic correction - the **compiler** isn't throwing any exception - your code compiles just fine. The runtime execution of this code causes an exception.

And more to the point, an array `a` has elements from `0` to `a.length - 1`. Your code attempts to access element number `a.length` and `a.length + 1`, which would both cause this exception. Since you reference `a[i + 1]` in the code, your loop should end at `a.length - 2`, or, in cleaner terms, the condition should be: `i < a.length - 1`. So, so summarize:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an out of bounds exception because of this line:

```
for(int i=0 ; i <= a.length ; i++){
```

It should be:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < a.length ; i++){
```

This is because arrays in c# are 0 indexed.

For example if an array has 10 elements and you access it like a[10], you get an out of bounds exception because the last element is a[9].

Answer (score 1):

array begin from index 0 so if arrays contain 3 element . the last element will be a[2]
so

```
for(int i=0 ; i <= a.length ; i++) must be for(int i=0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
```

and must check if i+1 < a.length or not

```
if(i+1 < a.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

For zero based indexing the range is `[0,a.length)`. Not only is the loop out of bounds, the `+1` goes even further out. Try,

```
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
    if (a[i] - a[i-1] > 0)
        counterup++;
```

Nitpicking, you only need one counter. Increment on up, decrement on down. Return true if the final count is greater than zero. You can omit the final condition (`==`) as well.